# jQuery code - can this be improved?

Tags: jquery

I have a page with 7 radio buttons, one for each day of the week. When a radio button is selected, I run this below code.

```
$('.radio-date').on("click", function(e) {
   //Hide all the markers
   $('.marker').hide();

   //Show markers for selected date
   $('.marker[data-date="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();

   //Loop thru each visible marker and set left/width to reposition
   $('.marker:visible').each(function(i) {
       var markerLeft = markerWidth * i;
       $(this).css({ left: markerLeft + '%', width: markerWidth + '%'});
   });
});
```

For certain weeks, when there are more than 1000 markers displayed on the page, there is a noticeable lag when I select a date. It takes about 1sec or more for the radio button to be checked/selected (and for the markers to show/hide) after I click on it.

Any suggestions on improving this code?

Thanks.

Comment: We would need to see the HTML and CSS. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)). Sounds to me like you could allow the browser to handle it with CSS, probably with floats, or if not with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given only the jQuery code, I'd say you should cache when it is possible:

```
$(function() {
    var markers = $('.marker');

    $('.radio-date').on("click", function(e) {
        //Hide all the markers
        markers.hide();

        //Show markers for selected date
        markers.filter('[data-date="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();

       //Loop thru each visible marker and set left/width to reposition
        markers.filter(':visible').each(function(i) {
            var markerLeft = markerWidth * i;
            $(this).css({ left: markerLeft + '%', width: markerWidth + '%'});
        });
    });
});
```